# Normalize names with different characters

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm working on a project in flutter in which I get a list of boardgames from a json file and show them in a ListView. But there are some games in which their names have different characters such as this one. Name: Tal der K**ö**nige

This is how this game is displayed: [Tal der K**ö**nige](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V7TkR.png)

Is there a way that I can normalize the names so that I can show them properly?

I have tried to use the dart package unorm_dart.

Comment: What do you mean by "normalize" and "properly"? Is your app so multi platform that is is running on MS Dos and ANSI? It should not be a problem for UNICODE text.

Comment: Maybe your json file is not UNICODE?

Comment: By "normalize" and "properly", I mean that it would be cool to display "Tal der Könige" instead of displaying "Tal der KÃ¶nige". And about the json file not being UNICODE, I'm going to look into it, 'cause it's actually not my file.